# Want to add lump-sum amount in TAX in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

I want to add some amount in TAX in magento. How this can be done?

Like in cart when we calculate shipping & handling at that time, shipping & handling comes but below that....TAX coming. I want to know the location from where the Tax is returned....something like this - return $tax; so that I can add an amount there & that will be used in whole site. I do not want a phtml file. I want a core file from which the tax is returned & I can add some amount & that will be used in whole site.

I checked the files inside Tax module built-in coming in magento but very hard to determine from where the final tax is returned :(

Another thing is I searched for it & got some solutions like add custom modules & through it add the custom fee but I do not want a separate module for it.

Any Help Please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find that on **tax/calculation** model.

Go to `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php` there you can find a function named `calcTaxAmount()` there you can see that the function is returning a variable name `$amount`. That is the **tax amount** which is being applied.

**Hope this help you to find your answer.**

Comment: Thank you Ashish for your quick reply :)  I am giving it a try & getting back to you. Thanks again Ashish :)

Comment: You made a spelling mistake on my name that will be **Asish** not **Ashish** :D :D

Comment: Let me know what happen

Comment: Hi Asish, yes you are right...sorry for the spelling mistake :) haha   Yes so now the situation is that.....we have some issues in server & it is not working right now....as soon as it starts working again....I will definitely get back to you :)  Thanks again Asish for helping here quickly :)

Comment: Hi Asish, Now the server issue resolved & working. You the great, Yes it is coming from there :) But I have one more  question :) I noticed that it is calculating per product so if I add 10 in coding then final amount which I can see in cart page after calculating shipping & handling is : Tax + 20 not Tax + 10 :) so from where can I get final amount of Tax? Although by any trick I can get it checked like if it is calculating for last product in cart or not...but wondering if I can get the final amount :)

Comment: As per my knowledge this is not possible to get the total amount.. You can do those trip you said... ::)

Comment: Yes ok Asish, ok so I am continuing on this one & will post if I got any fruitful thing but you have provided the exact file and method here so that is enough for me to go ahead :)  Thank Asish for your great help :)